# I'm Indonesian, can I leave Frankfurt airport without a visa when I'm waiting for a connecting flight to London?

Tags: visas, eu, visas-on-arrival, indonesian-citizens

So far I know that Indonesians need a visa to visit Germany (EU) however I will have a UK visa on my passport, and a ticket (connecting flight to London), and my question is pretty obvious:

Are all those documents good enough to pass through immigration? Or do I need to apply for a German visa in the German embassy for a really short visit? or is there some special counter that can do a visa on arrival in the airport? Can anyone give me an answer?

Answer (score 8):

As an Indonesian Citizen transiting Germany when travelling between two non-Schengen countries you do not need a visa, presuming you are passing through one of the following airports :
Cologne/Bonn (CGN), Frankfurt (FRA), Munich (MUC), Hamburg (HAM), or Dusseldorf (DUS).

When traveling through these airports you will be able to "Transit Without Visa" (TWOV), however as you will not have a Visa you will have to remain "airside" and will not be allowed to pass through 'Passport Control' and enter the country.

If you wish to enter Germany, even briefly, you will require a Visa.  Visa's are NOT available at the airport, and would need to be arranged in advance.

If you are travelling through Berlin Tegel (TXL) then you MAY also be able TWOV, however it depends on the exact details of your arrival/departure, and you should contact your airline to confirm what is required.

Comment: A little side note to explain the logic behind Doc entirely accurate answer. There is very little difference between entering to see the city during a long layover at the airport, entering to connect to a Schengen-only flight and entering to stay in the country for some time. The ways rules are structured, either you stay airside (in which case rules regarding transit apply) or you need to have the right to enter the Schengen area or get an entry-and-stay visa. There is no in-between.